# Running scala program

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, grammar

I am having trouble running a program in scala. I am very new to the language and was not able to set it up in intellij so I am now using sublime and trying to run it in the terminal. When I try to run the microproject class I keep getting arrayindexoutofbounds error.

If somebody could please help me figure out how to run this program that would be great.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

abstract class MatchTree
case class S(e:MatchTree) extends MatchTree
case class E(c:MatchTree, e:MatchTree) extends MatchTree
case class C(s:String) extends MatchTree
case class NIL() extends MatchTree

class MPParser extends JavaTokenParsers{
def s: Parser[MatchTree] = e ^^ {case se => S(se)}
def e: Parser[MatchTree] = c ~ e ^^ {case ch ~ ex => E(ch,ex)} | c ^^ {case 
ch => E(ch,NIL())}
def c[C] = ("a" | "b") ^^ {case ch => C(ch)}
}

object Microproject extends MPParser{
def main(args: Array[String]) {
println("input : "+ args(0))
println(parseAll(s, args(0)))
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the program requires you to pass an argument to it. You can do this like so (on the command line):

```
scala myFile.scala "Some argument"
```

This is what should have clued you in on this:

```
println("input : "+ args(0))
```

As you can see, this line prints out the first argument to the program (`args(0)`). Next time, you can look at the stack trace to see which line the error is occurring on and see if you can figure out what is going on there. Also, in the future, you may be more likely to get help running your professor's programs from your professor than from the internet. You got lucky this time...

Also, I don't know what argument the program expects. You'll have to ask your professor that.